# Flat list does not show in other component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Flat list does not show in react native. I want to pass information to another component, I'm rendering using flatList, but nothing appears on the screen and I don't get the error ...  is my other component that will receive the information

my flatList :

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({item}) => {<Item {...item} />}}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        ListHeaderComponent={<Cabecalho />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

MY COMPONENT WHAT SHOULD YOU RENDER

```
export const Item = ({titulo}) => {
    
    return (
            <View>
                <Text >{titulo}</Text>
            </View>
    );
}
```

DATA:

```
export const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      titulo: 'Abajur',
      imagem: require('../assets/images/01-tablelamps.png'),
      estudio: 'Jim&Jill Designs',
      itemName: 'Wilson',
      preco: 92.1,
      itemDesc:
        'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text',
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's happened because renderItems doesn't return any component to fix this change

```
 renderItem={({item}) => {<Item {...item} />}}
```

to

```
  renderItem={({item}) => {return <Item {...item} />}}
```

or

```
 renderItem={({item}) => <Item {...item} />}
```